# To Delete an Entry in a Nested Map in c++

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have a map declared as

```
std::map< std::string, std::map<int,std::list<pointers*> > myMap; // in c++.
```

May I know in order to delete an entry in this map, is it sufficient by calling myMap.erase(entryToBeDeleted)? Or should I go and iterate through the sub-map to delete everything first and then delete the entry?

To add on, the inner map is a map with int as key and a list of pointers as value

Comment: What types does your inner map contain?

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. the inner map is a map with int as key and a list of pointers as value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the real type of the nested map, if it contains raw pointer, it's your responsibilty to iterate though each item of nested map to deallocate the memory. Otherwise, `myMap.erase(entryToBeDeleted)` is sufficient.

**Edit:**

As your nested map has list of pointers, you need to go through each list inside each nested map to delete pointers.

A better way is to use smart pointers:

```
std::map< std::string, std::map<int,std::list<std::unique_ptr<pointers> > > myMap;
```

When you delete nested map, the pointers will be deallocated automatically.

Comment: That's not what he wants to do. He wants to remove an element from the *outer* map and is unsure whether he has to take care of cleaning up the inner map associated to it...

Answer (score 0):

the erase function should be sufficient as it is meant for removing an entry.

reference to this if you have any more doubts http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/erase/

Answer (score 0):

If you delete the entry from the outer map, it will actively remove the objects from the inner map. Deleting `outer[i]` will destroy (i.e. call the destructor) for `outer[i].first` and `outer[i].second`, which means the inner map's destructor will be called for that element. Calling the inner map's destructor will iteratively call the destructors for all elements/objects within (both key and value).